# finding column vectors - linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, regression, linear-transformations

$L:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ with bases

$\mathcal{S}=\left\{\left(-1,1,0\right),\left(0,1,1\right),\left(1,0,0\right)\right\} \: \text{for} \:\mathbb{R}^3 \:\text{and} \\
\mathcal{T}=\left\{\left(1,2\right),\left(1,-1\right)\right\}\: \text{for} \:\mathbb{R}^2.\:$

The matrix of $L$ with respect to $\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{T}$ is:
$A=\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 1 \\ 
-1 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$

I used the formula $A\bf{x}$ $= \bf{b}$ to compute $\left[L\left(v_1\right)\right]_\mathcal{T}$ and ended up with $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}^\mathcal{T}$, but this answer is wrong according to the study guide I'm working from. The answer it has is $\begin{bmatrix}1\\ -1\end{bmatrix}^\mathcal{T}$.
What am I doing wrong?

my work:$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 1 \\-1 & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}-1 \\1 \\0\end{pmatrix}\:=\:\begin{pmatrix}1 \\2\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Do you understand what "matrix of $L$ with respect to $S$ and $T$" means?

Comment: @SantiagoCanez, your comment doesn't help at all.

Comment: The work you gave supporting your answer suggests that you don't quite understand what is being asked for, hence my question. You've accepted a correct answer below, but without understanding _why_ it is correct you will likely have trouble with related concepts. Do you understand why the answer should be the first column of the matrix $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have things defined, it looks like you can read off the column vectors you seek from that matrix with respect to the linear transformation. The matrix of $L$ with respect to $\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{T}$ is one that is precisely
$$\begin{bmatrix}[L\mathbf{v_1}]_{\mathcal{T}} & [L\mathbf{v_2}]_{\mathcal{T}} & [L\mathbf{v_3}]_{\mathcal{T}}\end{bmatrix}$$
where $(\mathbf{v_1},\mathbf{v_2},\mathbf{v_3})$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$, and $[L\mathbf{v_j}]_{\mathcal{T}}$ is a column vector of the coordinates of $L\mathbf{v_j}$ with respect to the basis $\mathcal{T}$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$. The work is already done for you.